# can connect to Samba, but can not access any file

Tags: samba, share

I have installed samba on my Centos 6.5 successfully. and I have also created samba users as well. in windows 7 client, I can connect to samba and I can see files, but when I try to open it, It says I can not access to it. 
this is my samba.conf:

```
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options (perhaps too
# many!) most of which are not shown in this example
#
# For a step to step guide on installing, configuring and using samba, 
# read the Samba-HOWTO-Collection. This may be obtained from:
#  http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/Samba-HOWTO-Collection.pdf
#
# Many working examples of smb.conf files can be found in the 
# Samba-Guide which is generated daily and can be downloaded from: 
#  http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/Samba-Guide.pdf
#
# Any line which starts with a ; (semi-colon) or a # (hash) 
# is a comment and is ignored. In this example we will use a #
# for commentry and a ; for parts of the config file that you
# may wish to enable
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command "testparm"
# to check that you have not made any basic syntactic errors. 
#
#---------------
# SELINUX NOTES:
#
# If you want to use the useradd/groupadd family of binaries please run:
# setsebool -P samba_domain_controller on
#
# If you want to share home directories via samba please run:
# setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs on
#
# If you create a new directory you want to share you should mark it as
# "samba_share_t" so that selinux will let you write into it.
# Make sure not to do that on system directories as they may already have
# been marked with othe SELinux labels.
#
# Use ls -ldZ /path to see which context a directory has
#
# Set labels only on directories you created!
# To set a label use the following: chcon -t samba_share_t /path
#
# If you need to share a system created directory you can use one of the
# following (read-only/read-write):
# setsebool -P samba_export_all_ro on
# or
# setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw on
#
# If you want to run scripts (preexec/root prexec/print command/...) please
# put them into the /var/lib/samba/scripts directory so that smbd will be
# allowed to run them.
# Make sure you COPY them and not MOVE them so that the right SELinux context
# is applied, to check all is ok use restorecon -R -v /var/lib/samba/scripts
#
#--------------
#
#======================= Global Settings =====================================

[global]

# ----------------------- Network Related Options -------------------------
#
# workgroup = NT-Domain-Name or Workgroup-Name, eg: MIDEARTH
#
# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
#
# netbios name can be used to specify a server name not tied to the hostname
#
# Interfaces lets you configure Samba to use multiple interfaces
# If you have multiple network interfaces then you can list the ones
# you want to listen on (never omit localhost)
#
# Hosts Allow/Hosts Deny lets you restrict who can connect, and you can
# specifiy it as a per share option as well
#
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    server string = Samba Server Version %v

    netbios name = server

;   interfaces = lo eth0 192.168.12.2/24 192.168.13.2/24 
;   hosts allow = 127. 192.168.12. 192.168.13.

# --------------------------- Logging Options -----------------------------
#
# Log File let you specify where to put logs and how to split them up.
#
# Max Log Size let you specify the max size log files should reach

    # logs split per machine
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    # max 50KB per log file, then rotate
    max log size = 50

# ----------------------- Standalone Server Options ------------------------
#
# Scurity can be set to user, share(deprecated) or server(deprecated)
#
# Backend to store user information in. New installations should 
# use either tdbsam or ldapsam. smbpasswd is available for backwards 
# compatibility. tdbsam requires no further configuration.

    security = user
    passdb backend = tdbsam


# ----------------------- Domain Members Options ------------------------
#
# Security must be set to domain or ads
#
# Use the realm option only with security = ads
# Specifies the Active Directory realm the host is part of
#
# Backend to store user information in. New installations should 
# use either tdbsam or ldapsam. smbpasswd is available for backwards 
# compatibility. tdbsam requires no further configuration.
#
# Use password server option only with security = server or if you can't
# use the DNS to locate Domain Controllers
# The argument list may include:
#   password server = My_PDC_Name [My_BDC_Name] [My_Next_BDC_Name]
# or to auto-locate the domain controller/s
#   password server = *


;   security = domain
;   passdb backend = tdbsam
;   realm = MY_REALM

;   password server = <NT-Server-Name>

# ----------------------- Domain Controller Options ------------------------
#
# Security must be set to user for domain controllers
#
# Backend to store user information in. New installations should 
# use either tdbsam or ldapsam. smbpasswd is available for backwards 
# compatibility. tdbsam requires no further configuration.
#
# Domain Master specifies Samba to be the Domain Master Browser. This
# allows Samba to collate browse lists between subnets. Don't use this
# if you already have a Windows NT domain controller doing this job
#
# Domain Logons let Samba be a domain logon server for Windows workstations. 
#
# Logon Scrpit let yuou specify a script to be run at login time on the client
# You need to provide it in a share called NETLOGON
#
# Logon Path let you specify where user profiles are stored (UNC path)
#
# Various scripts can be used on a domain controller or stand-alone
# machine to add or delete corresponding unix accounts
#
;   security = user
;   passdb backend = tdbsam

;   domain master = yes 
;   domain logons = yes

    # the login script name depends on the machine name
;   logon script = %m.bat
    # the login script name depends on the unix user used
;   logon script = %u.bat
;   logon path = \\%L\Profiles\%u
    # disables profiles support by specifing an empty path
;   logon path =          

;   add user script = /usr/sbin/useradd "%u" -n -g users
;   add group script = /usr/sbin/groupadd "%g"
;   add machine script = /usr/sbin/useradd -n -c "Workstation (%u)" -M -d /nohome -s /bin/false "%u"
;   delete user script = /usr/sbin/userdel "%u"
;   delete user from group script = /usr/sbin/userdel "%u" "%g"
;   delete group script = /usr/sbin/groupdel "%g"


# ----------------------- Browser Control Options ----------------------------
#
# set local master to no if you don't want Samba to become a master
# browser on your network. Otherwise the normal election rules apply
#
# OS Level determines the precedence of this server in master browser
# elections. The default value should be reasonable
#
# Preferred Master causes Samba to force a local browser election on startup
# and gives it a slightly higher chance of winning the election
;   local master = no
;   os level = 33
;   preferred master = yes

#----------------------------- Name Resolution -------------------------------
# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
#
# - WINS Support: Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable it's WINS Server
#
# - WINS Server: Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
#
# - WINS Proxy: Tells Samba to answer name resolution queries on
#   behalf of a non WINS capable client, for this to work there must be
#   at least one    WINS Server on the network. The default is NO.
#
# DNS Proxy - tells Samba whether or not to try to resolve NetBIOS names
# via DNS nslookups.

;   wins support = yes
;   wins server = w.x.y.z
;   wins proxy = yes

;   dns proxy = yes

# --------------------------- Printing Options -----------------------------
#
# Load Printers let you load automatically the list of printers rather
# than setting them up individually
#
# Cups Options let you pass the cups libs custom options, setting it to raw
# for example will let you use drivers on your Windows clients
#
# Printcap Name let you specify an alternative printcap file
#
# You can choose a non default printing system using the Printing option

    load printers = yes
    cups options = raw

;   printcap name = /etc/printcap
    #obtain list of printers automatically on SystemV
;   printcap name = lpstat
;   printing = cups

# --------------------------- Filesystem Options ---------------------------
#
# The following options can be uncommented if the filesystem supports
# Extended Attributes and they are enabled (usually by the mount option
# user_xattr). Thess options will let the admin store the DOS attributes
# in an EA and make samba not mess with the permission bits.
#
# Note: these options can also be set just per share, setting them in global
# makes them the default for all shares

;   map archive = no
;   map hidden = no
;   map read only = no
;   map system = no
;   store dos attributes = yes


#============================ Share Definitions ==============================

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    browseable = yes
    writable = yes
    valid users = Mohamed Moussa
    public = yes
;   valid users = MYDOMAIN\%S

[iam] 
    comment = Partage De fichier Contable
    browseable = yes
    writable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    path = /ITFiles
    valid users = Mohamed Moussa
    public = yes 

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/spool/samba
    browseable = no
    guest ok = no
    writable = no
    printable = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
;   [netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /var/lib/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   writable = no
;   share modes = no


# Un-comment the following to provide a specific roving profile share
# the default is to use the user's home directory
;   [Profiles]
;   path = /var/lib/samba/profiles
;   browseable = no
;   guest ok = yes


# A publicly accessible directory, but read only, except for people in
# the "staff" group
;   [public]
;   comment = Public Stuff
;   path = /home/samba
;   public = yes
;   writable = yes
;   printable = no
;   write list = +staff
```

Comment: Could you please improve the formatting? As it stands, it's quite hard to read. You could use four space indentation for `samba.conf`. Regarding your question: I guess it's a permission problem.

Comment: What is the state of your SElinux ?

Comment: @gf_ The faster way to improve formatting is to highlight the code and press `Ctrl+k`, which will add the 4 spaces to all highlighted lines.

Comment: can somebody give me a solution pleaseee

Comment: @Midou with the rather vague information you have provided it's unlikely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably due to SELINUX. For a quick fix, try putting SELINUX into permissive (ie: non-blocking) mode by running that command:

```
setenforce 0
```

If it works, you can consider to permanentely put SELINUX into permissive mode by editing the `/etc/selinux/config` file

Anyway, this is **not recommended**, as SELINUX is a valuable security subsystem. The canonical way to let SELINUX convive with Samba is by marking the directory you are sharing with the correct security tag/context. For example, regarding you `[iam]` share, you should issue the following commands:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t "/ITFiles(/.*)?"
restorecon -RF /ITFiles
```

Another possibility is to set **all** filesystem directory as Samba-enabled, using the SELINUX booleans `samba_export_all_rw`. For example, issuing the command:

```
setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw on
```

will enable read/write access to **all** filesytem direcotory. While insecure, this is better than totally disable SELINUX.

Comment: thank you!! by using setenforce 0 it worked properly..but is it permanent shodanshok?

Comment: No, after a reboot it will revert to enforcing. As stated above, to make it permanent you need to either edit the /etc/selinux/config and set selinux to permissive or leave it enabled and edit the file/directory tags using semanage and restorecon. If you don't want to mess with changing system config, simple use the third option above, issuing setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw on